# XPM Ribbon toolbar getting disabled after finish editing

Tags: experience-manager, dynamic-publishing

I have a Page where Components are getting fetched using dynamic CT. I have enabled XPM in-line editing and able to get the option to edit the Component and multi-value fields inside the same but once I click on Finish editing it shows "All changes committed" and Page reloads. But ribbon toolbar gets disabled after this.

If I open this Page in new tab then my changes reflect. I don't even get any error but still not able to continue with the editing once tool bar gets disabled.

Comment: Please check this issue with sdl support team. i think it`s browser cache issue.